# How can I calculate mean over a list of 2D matrices?

Tags: r

I have a list of 2D matrices which I want to calculate some statistics on it, for example calculate the mean. I can convert the list to array and use apply like:

```
dat1<-list(a = matrix(seq(1,4),2,2), b= matrix(seq(5,8),2,2), c= matrix(seq(9,12),2,2))

# convert to array 
obs <-array(unlist(dat1), dim = c(2, 2, 3))
meanObs <- apply(obs, c(1,2), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Is there anyway to perform this without converting the list to array?!! Calculating the mean directly from list.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the array? Lists are can hold objects of mixed types so generally functions don't usually combine elements of a list for analysis. For example you can have arrays of different dimensions in your list which would make things ugly. Usually you need tell R how to properly combine the data.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid going through conversion to array, to reduce the coding. But if there is no other way, then I will go for it.

Comment: @jilber's answer at the duplicate question, `apply(simplify2array(mylist), c(1,2), mean)` is probably what you want (and will generalize to any summary statistic)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since it's the mean you want, I think you can do

```
 Reduce("+",dat1)/length(dat1)
```

`Reduce()` takes the sum of the matrices, element by element, in pairs.  Then you just have to divide by N.

This *could* work for other statistics (e.g. `Reduce(pmax,dat1)` should give you the elementwise maxima) but would be harder if you were trying to compute some other summary statistic such as the median ...  in that case I don't think you could avoid looping (implicitly or explicitly) over the elements of the matrices.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is very nice at least for some simple statistics. Unfortunately, I have a bunch of them to calculate like median and quantile and ... so maybe I will stick to converting to array then.